# Implementing Correlation and Correlation matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I would like to implement covariance and correlation matrix without using the inbuilt function.

My codes:

```
u1 = 1; u2 = 0; sigma1 = 1; sigma2 = 2; N = 1000

X = norm.rvs(u1 , sigma1,size=(1 , N))
Y= norm.rvs(u2 , sigma2,size=(1 , N))
XY =  np.concatenate((X,Y))
fact = N - 1 
cov_mat = np.dot(XY.T, XY.conj()) / fact
print(cov_mat)
```

The Results

```
[[ 0.000136   -0.00045308  0.00041102 ... -0.00066916 -0.00048639
  -0.00053653]
 [-0.00045308  0.00686947  0.00272365 ...  0.00294479  0.00971417
   0.00538347]
 [ 0.00041102  0.00272365  0.0043675  ... -0.00147591  0.00471047
   0.00112446]
 ...
 [-0.00066916  0.00294479 -0.00147591 ...  0.00338792  0.00347361
   0.0031199 ]
 [-0.00048639  0.00971417  0.00471047 ...  0.00347361  0.01396131
   0.00734893]
 [-0.00053653  0.00538347  0.00112446 ...  0.0031199   0.00734893
   0.00452921]]
```

The results are not as I expect. kindly assist.

Using np.cov(), the result is:

```
[[0.98423898 0.01737643]
 [0.01737643 3.8532223 ]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: What are the expected results?

Comment: Using the np.cov(), The result is [[0.98423898 0.01737643]
 [0.01737643 3.8532223 ]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **covariance matrix** between `X` and `Y` looks like this:

```
|  var_X  cov_XY |
| cov_XY   var_Y |
```

You have `var_X = E[(X - E[X])²]`, similarly `var_Y = E[(Y - E[Y])²]`, and `cov(X, Y) = E[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y])]`. `cov(X, Y)` is symetric.

You can measure those with:

```
>>> var_X = ((X - X.mean())**2).mean()

>>> var_Y = ((Y - Y.mean())**2).mean()

>>> cov_XY = ((X - X.mean())*(Y - Y.mean())).mean()
```

---

The **correlation matrix** between `X` and `Y`, however looks like:

```
|   1     r_YX |
|  r_XY      1 |
```

Where `r_XY = cov_XY / (std_X*std_Y)`, this implies symetry for `corr(X, Y)`

Using `cov_XY`, `var_X`, and `var_Y`, the correletion matrix can be constructed from:

```
>>> corr_XY = cov_XY / np.sqrt(var_X*var_Y)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response. However, I need a covariance  and correlation matrix of the concatenated X and Y

Comment: @MicahKOndiwa, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.